# Lucene.Net query with leading wildcard

Tags: lucene.net

Good afternoon,

I need to be able to search a Lucene.Net index with a wild card prefix; i.e. now when I search for the word "paint" "autopaint" does not come up, but I need it to.

I have seen mentioned "SetAllowLeadingWildcard" elsewhere in Stack Overflow, but I don't see that property - maybe because I'm using Lucene.NET?

Thanks,
Mo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Lucene.Net are you using? The [SetAllowLeadingWildcard](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard.html) property is on [QueryParser](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.html) in v2.1.

To be able to search for `paint` and get `autopaint` back as a result, you would have to search for `*paint`. Searching for `paint` would *not* return `autopaint`.

Take heed of the note in the comments on the property though:

> Note that this can produce very slow queries on big indexes.